# Here Map Attributes v8 to v7 - Convert tileIds to tileXYs

Tags: here-api, heremaps

Currently, our application uses Here Map Attributes API v7 and the response looks like this

```
https://pde.api.here.com/1/index.json?app_id=&app_code=&layer=ROAD_GEOM_FCn&attributes=LINK_ID&values=17339738,17339811

{
    "Layers":
    [
        {
            "layer": "ROAD_GEOM_FC3",
            "level": 11,
            "tileXYs":
            [
                {
                    "x": 2000,
                    "y": 1611
                },
                {
                    "x": 2009,
                    "y": 1611
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

We're trying to migrate to new V8 API and having issues with translating the response model. In v8 the response returns tileIds (instead of tileXYs)

```
https://smap.hereapi.com/v8/maps/index.json?layer=ROAD_GEOM_FCn&attributes=LINK_ID&values=17339738,17339811&apiKey=

{
    "Layers":
    [
        {
            "layer": "ROAD_GEOM_FC3",
            "level": 11,
            "tileIDs":
            [
                6600656,
                6600665
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way I can convert tileIds into tileXYs similar to the legacy response?

I tried to convert lat and long from this API endpoint like in the docs but didn't work.

```
https://developer.here.com/documentation/content-map-attributes/dev_guide/topics/here-map-content.html

https://smap.hereapi.com/v8/maps/attributes.json?layers=ROAD_GEOM_FC3&in=tile:6600656&apikey=
```

Answer (score 1):

**First variant:**

```
Calculates tileX and tileY out of a given tileId and a level
    @param tileId - the tile id
    @param level - the PDE layer level
    @param tileXYLevel - this OUT parameter is filed with tileX, tileY and the level
*/
public void getTileXYLevel(long tileId, int level, int tileXYLevel[])  throws Exception
{
  if (isStaticContent) {
      tileXYLevel[0] = 0;
      tileXYLevel[1] = 0;
      tileXYLevel[2] = 0;
      return;
  }
  int numTilesVertical = 1L << level;
  int tileX = (int)(tileId % (2 * numTilesVertical));
  if (tileX < 0 || tileX >= numTilesVertical * 2)
      throw new Exception("Invalid tileX=" + tileX + " for level " + level + ", must be [0 ... " + (numTilesVertical * 2 - 1) + "]");
  int tileY = (int)((tileId - tileX) / (2 * numTilesVertical));
  if (tileY < 0 || tileY >= numTilesVertical)
      throw new Exception("Invalid tileY=" + tileY + " for level " + level + ", must be [0 ... " + (numTilesVertical     - 1) + "]");
  tileXYLevel[0] = tileX;
  tileXYLevel[1] = tileY;
  tileXYLevel[2] = level;
}
```

**Second variant:**
Regarding this formulas:

```
      tile size = 180° / 2^level [degree]
      tileY = trunc((latitude  +  90°) / tile size)
      tileX = trunc((longitude + 180°) / tile size)
      tileID = tileY * 2 * (2^level) + tileX
```

This is not possible. At least it is needed to know whether latitude or longitude then you can calculate tileX or tileY.

Better way is:

1.Request this https://smap.hereapi.com/v8/maps/attributes.json?layers=ROAD_GEOM_FC3&in=tile:6600656&apikey=

In fist Row of response you have:

```
Meta: {
layerName: "ROAD_GEOM_FC3",
tileId: 6600656,
level: 11,
mapRegion: "WEU",
mapRelease: "22125",
},    
Rows: [
    {
    LINK_ID: "17339811",
    LONG_HAUL: "N",
    NAME: "B4304",
    NAMES: "ENGBNB4304",
    TUNNEL: "N",
    BRIDGE: "N",
    LAT: "5167314,16,9,10",
    LON: "-417072,-9,-6,-9",
    ZLEVEL: ",,,",
    ELEVATION: ",,,",
    TOPOLOGY_ID: "98996232",
    START_OFFSET: "0",
    }
```

Then you have from LAT, LON:

lat: 51.67314; lng: -4.17072

2.From above coordinate you calculate tileX and tileY, see please Javascript example:

```
var
   degSize = 180 / Math.pow(2, level),
   tileY = Math.floor((lat + 90) / degSize),
   tileX = Math.floor((lng + 180) / degSize);
```

You know from response of https://smap.hereapi.com/v8/maps/index.json? that level is 11 (or you know it from "Meta" property)

After calculation we have tileX = 2000 and tileY = 1611